# test not working in ChromeDriver but working fine in FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to test a website on ChromDriver. As it goes to the welcome page it won't respond. I am not getting any exception but the code is not doing anything. Same code is working for FirefoxDriver without any code change.

Java Code ---->>

```
public class Screen_1_Monster {
WebDriver driver;
 WebElement wb;

   public void operation() throws InterruptedException,NoSuchElementException{
     String lastUpdate, update;  
       try{
       // driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\New Folder\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
      //going to the desired website
      driver.get("https://my.monsterindia.com/login.html?src=http://my.monsterindia.com/my_monster.html&rand=5257");
      //maximize
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      //wait
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }catch(Exception e){
          //Get status of Welcome page
          driver.get("https://my.monsterindia.com/login.html?src=http://my.monsterindia.com/my_monster.html&rand=5257");
          //maximize
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          //wait
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }//catch


     //Entering the UserName
     try{
         wb=driver.findElement(By.id("BodyContent:txtUsername"));
         wb.click();
         wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan@gmail.com");
     }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
         wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BodyContent:txtUsername']"));
         wb.click();
         wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan@gmail.com");
     }//catch


     //Entering the Password
     try{
         wb=driver.findElement(By.id("BodyContent_txtPassword"));
         wb.click();
         wb.sendKeys("ari2738");  
     }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
         wb=driver.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='BodyContent_txtPassword']"));
         wb.click();
         wb.sendKeys("ari2738");      
     }//catch


     //Clicking on Login button
     try{
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }//catch


     //if Usename/Password is incorrect
     try{
        wb=driver.findElement(By.className("txt_red")); 
         String error = wb.getText();
         String expected="Please recheck, Username/E-mail id/Password is incorrect. Remember you can also login with your E-mail id. (Please check if the box is ticked in case e-mail id is selected)";
         if(expected.length()==error.length()){
             System.out.println(error);
             driver.close();
         }//if
     }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
     }//catch


     **//Closing the pop up**
     try{
         driver.navigate().refresh();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ProfileOverlay_close_other']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.className("flyout_close")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
     }//catch

     }//operation


   public static void main(String args[]) throws  InterruptedException {
       Screen_1_Monster s = new Screen_1_Monster();
       s.operation();

   }
}//Screen_1_Monster
```

The above code wont works after it goes to  //Closing the pop up try catch block

Comment: Which is the "pop up try catch"? Also it appears that your try/catches are just calling the same actions a second time if they fail the first time.

Comment: @Mark Rowlands Just before the main method. I commented it as //Closing the pop up

Answer (score -1):

It might be worthwhile trying out something like `driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());`
If not this then some other flavor like `driver.switchTo().window("<window name>");`

This seems to be a case of the window that you want to click the close button on is not getting focussed.